# Text editor for Mac which uses git to save files

Tags: git, text-editor

I want a text editor in mac which supports saving files directly in git.
i.e. I want git commit to get executed every time I save the file.

I am not comfortable using command line editors like vi and emacs, so a GUI editor will be better.

Presently I use TextWrangler and am trying out Sublime Text 2 and from command line doing a git commit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a commit every time you save, but I think that there are some git plugins for Eclipse which will allow you to commit from within the editor. Vim's git-fugitive plugin would be great for this but as you said you don't want to go that way.

I'm not sure you will find much... one of the ideas behind using git is to have nice clean history of your development... committing on every save is unlikely to give you this, so people don't really make editors to behave in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think there is such a thing. As zoran119 said, it is important to keep a clean commit history as this allows you to really view your process and ideally, every commit should result in a decent version of the source code. In a programming context, this means that everything should build properly, but you can image similar constraints for any content based application (e.g. no phrases ending mid-sentence). Another concern may be the lack of reliable commit messages, as these make your history far more useful than automatically generated (or empty) messages.

There are however tools that allow you to use git to store different versions in a scheme such as the one you want: e.g. [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/). This is a program similar to DropBox, where the versioning backend is git. Whenever a file changes, it commits the changes.
I do have to note that I don't use SparkleShare, so your mileage may vary, certainly as I'm not completely sure whether the moment of the commit is identical on every possible operating system. But by using such a system, you can use virtually any text editor.

You can also consider GUI alternatives to vim such as gvim. Gvim has all features of vim in the command line, but the added advantage that you also have access to some menus which provide both a reminder of vim's shortcuts and visual access to common text processing commands and you will eventually learn to use its powerful features.